# Determining current file's location in R to include file from same directory?

Tags: r, filesystems, system

I want to be able to `source()` a file which includes a different file in its same directory, but I don't want to have to set the working directory from the R-prompt before running this file:

```
> getwd()
[1] "/Users/myser"
> source("/Users/myuser/workspace/myproject/myfile.r")
```

Inside /Users/myuser/workspace/myproject, there would be myfile.r and my-utils.r.  myfile.r calls `source('my-utils.r')` from within it.

Other programming languages can determine the current file's path. Does R have something similar? Example:

```
cur_dir <- sys.get_current_file_path()
source(file.path(cur_dir, "my-utils.r"))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
source("/Users/myuser/workspace/myproject/my-utils.r", chdir=TRUE)
```

When `chdir` option is set to true and the source file parameter is a full path, the directory of file will be used as the working directory while sourcing the file.

NOTE: `cur_dir <- sys.get_current_file_path()` doesn't make much sense because pathnames are not unique.

Comment: beat my by 30 seconds... nice answer.

Comment: @Apprentice - my function name was probably poorly chosen.  What I meant was something like this Python code: os.path.realpath(\_\_file\_\_)

Comment: The problem with this code/solution is that it ties the functionality of that call to `source` to it existing in that specific directory. It would be good to have a solution that did not depend on this, such as would be achievable by the approach which dolan was shooting for with his python inspired pseudo example. correct me if I'm missing something though.

Comment: This is not a solution at all. The point is to avoid putting  "/Users/myuser/workspace/myproject" in the code.

Comment: @Jfly, how do you expect to run /A/B/C.r from another location without somewhere telling R that it is located at /A/B?  You could use environment variables or write your own file searching function; but regardless, a directory name needs to be placed somewhere.  The point of the OP was how to execute with a different working directory not how to hide a constant.

Comment: The point of the OP is in the example followed "Does R have something similar? Example:"      The simple answer is: R can't do it.

Comment: @Jfly that wasn't the OP's point. It was to get something running using the directory of its source file. One idea he had was to extract it from within code. Yes, this technique is not available from R. And even in (interpreted) languages that provide such a technique, it doesn't always work because not all code comes from the filesystem (eg, it can come straight from memory).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's *very* late, but for people of the future, I ran into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35842119/3167040) on getting the directory where the script being sourced is.

I think you should be able to do this without installing additional packages:

```r
cur_dir = utils::getSrcDirectory(function(){})[1]
source(file.path(cur_dir, 'my-utils.R'))
```