# R setting working directory to source file location?

Tags: r

I read this topic:
[R command for setting working directory to source file location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672720/r-command-for-setting-working-directory-to-source-file-location)

But this function prints error:

```
this.dir <- dirname(parent.frame(2)$ofile)
setwd(this.dir)
```

> Error in dirname(parent.frame(2)$ofile) :    a character vector
>   argument expected

How can I set working directory to source file location?

Comment: What does parent.frame(2)$ofile give you?

Comment: > parent.frame(2)$ofile
NULL

Comment: Are you running the file using source?

Comment: im dont understand, im create new empty R file test.r and im want write comand.which will be change working directory

Comment: Works for me. I have `/tmp/test.R` with `print(dirname(parent.frame(2)$ofile))` and `source("/tmp/test.R")` prints `"/tmp"` as expected. What **exactly** are you doing?

Comment: im run commend print(dirname(parent.frame(2)$ofile)) But its return error Error in dirname(parent.frame(2)$ofile) : 
  a character vector argument expected