# How can I set different directory to the current directory in R?

Tags: r, path, directory

I'm trying to open a file that does not exist in my current directory. This file is named `testFile.r` existing in the `data` folder in my current directory. I tried `file.path("./data")` and then wanted to show the file with this command `file.show("testFile.r")` but it gives this error:

> Error: File testFile.r does not exist.

And the command `getwd()` gives the previous current directory. So any thoughts on this?

Comment: Just use `setwd()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R command for setting working directory to source file location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672720/r-command-for-setting-working-directory-to-source-file-location)

Comment: Thank you, but I need to keep both directories because I can switch between them easily. Is there a way like `addpath` in MATLAB ?

Comment: What does "keep both directories" mean? You could do `old_dir <- getwd(); setwd(new_dir);` and then `getwd(old_dir)` later on, if that is what you want.

Comment: Suppose I have more than two directories. Is there a vector that can contain multiple directories so that I can just concatenate what I need because I'm too lazy to store the old directories. But anyways your answer is simple and I can do it but I prefer something like `addpath` in MATLAB or `sys.path.append()` in python.

Comment: Check out `.libpaths` for setting the paths to R libraries, but this is not the same as setting the working directory, which can only be a single path on any OS known to me.

Answer (score 0):

You change your current directory using the command `setwd(new_directory)`
(replacing `new_directory` with the path to the directory you want).

If you'd rather stay in your current directory, just do

```
file.show("./data/testFile.r")
```

To keep track of multiple paths, you can save each as a variable and use the paste function to reference the file:

```
path1 <- "./data/"
path2 <- "./second_folder_name/"
file.show(paste0(path1, "testFile.R"))
file.show(paste0(path2, "testFile.R"))
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to keep both directories because I can switch between them easily. Is there a way like `addpath` in MATLAB ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with MATLAB, so I can't address this directly.  However, you can easily save the path as a text.  I'll edit my answer accordingly.