# Python command for setting working directory to source file location in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I want a python line of code that sets the working directory to folder the code is part of. I am using spyder IDE for writing and running python codes.

Side note: This question is very similar to [R command for setting working directory to source file location in Rstudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672720/r-command-for-setting-working-directory-to-source-file-location-in-rstudio)

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem I run into when developing in Jupyter for the command line.

You can try this to find where your script is executing from:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

def myPath():
    '''
    return the current working directory in both interpeters and when exectued on the commandline
    '''
    try:
        # path of this file when executed
        wd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    except NameError as e:
        print('this script is running in an interpreter')
        # if not found 
        wd = Path().resolve()    
    return(wd)
```