# R: source() and path to source files

Tags: r, function, relative-path, chdir

There must be something that I don't understand about the `source()` command in R. I'm still new to it, but I cannot for the life of me understand how it gets its directories from! My problem is this:

I have a wrapper script, `wrapper.R`, and a source file containing some functions, `functions.R`. Both of these are in the same directory. If I call `source('functions.R')` inside the wrapper script, while standing inside the directory where both files are located, everything is fine. However, I want to be able to run my `wrapper.R` script from some *other* directory, *i.e.* not the one where these script are located. If I run my wrapper for another directory, it doesn't work, and I get a `cannot open the file` error.

I googled and found lots of different threads, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048436/r-sourcing-files-using-a-relative-path) seemed to be very clear. The way I understand it, the way I'm doing it *should work*. Clearly, I'm misunderstanding something. My reading of that thread leads me to believe that `source()` works on the directory in which the file that calls `source()` is located in. My reading also leads me to believe that I should not be using `chdir = TRUE`, as I want to keep the advertised relative directory.

Seeing as it doesn't work... what am I misunderstanding? How can I source files in the same directory as my wrapper script when called from somewhere else?

Comment: This should all just come down to the working directory. R needs to know where to look for the files. You can find your current working directory by typing `getwd()` and you can reset it with `setwd()`. But you could always just do something like source("c:\...") and that should work.

Comment: Sorry, I was being unclear. I can set the working directory, but what if I'm trying to distribute these scripts to a colleague? I won't know exactly where he put them. Is there a way to `source` the files without actually knowing the directory, and still call the wrapper function from some other directory?

Comment: I believe if you write a bat file to run the scripts it will automatically use the directory it is in as the working directory.

Comment: Linking related older question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222107

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**If you are distributing a script to colleagues, you should really not be writing a script that sources other scripts.**  What if you want to rename or move `functions.R` in the future?  What if you need to modify a function in `functions.R`, but `wrapper.R` relies on the older version of that function?  It's a flimsy solution that will cause headache.  I would recommend either of the following instead.

1. Put everything needed into a single, self-contained script and distribute that.
2. If you *really* want to separate code into different files, write a package.  Might sound like overkill, but packages can actually be very simple and lightweight.  In the simplest form a package is just a directory with a `DESCRIPTION` and `NAMESPACE` file along with an `R/` directory.  Hadley breaks this down nicely: https://r-pkgs.org/whole-game.html.

Comment: Aaah, okay, that was a concept I didn't really envision... If I want to go the "package"-route, what if my project is a mixed-language project? If I have a small number of Python scripts in addition to the R ones? What would be a good way to distribute such a project?

Comment: If you want to go the package route, create a directory in your package called `inst/python/` and put the python scripts in there.  More info from Hadley: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/inst.html#inst-other-langs.

Comment: If you want to do a single R script followed by a single python script, feather is probably your best option.  It is the best way to share data.frame-like objects between R and python (I'm assuming this is data-pipeline script): https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/03/29/feather/

Comment: @Sajber feel free to accept this answer if it helped :)

Comment: It did help, thanks! Related question: now that I've gone the package route (it was easier than I initially thought, at least the R parts), how would I distribute the wrapper script? The wrapper should only be run from the command line, so it's not really part of the package itself (if I understand package strucutre correctly), but calls all the functions in the package. Where should I put the file? How do I make it available together with the package, but make it clear that it should be run from the command line?

Comment: You should place them in `exec/`, and when you install the package place a sym link in your `$PATH` that links to `/path/to/your/installed/package/exec/your_script`.  Also make sure you learn how to use devtools, particularly `load_all()`.

Comment: "Put everything needed into a single, self-contained script and distribute that."

Bad, bad, bad programming practice. Readability counts.

Comment: "In the simplest form a package is just a directory..." this is oversimplified. The _source_ for a package is a directory with certain files and subdirs, but to actually _load_ the package into R, it has to be compiled first. This can be tricky for a beginner.

Answer (score 30):

You can do this using the [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/here/index.html) package. It uses the "current working directory at the time when the package is loaded". In other words, the directory you start your R session from.

In your case the code would be:

```
source(here::here('functions.R'))
```

This will work even if the wrapper script `wrapper.R` is in a different directory in the project.

If `functions.R` is in a subdirectory of the project, just add it to the call to `here()`, to complete the relative path:

```
source(here::here('subdirectory', 'functions.R'))
```

Comment: I just discovered the `here` package and it is solving all sorts of file path issues for me. I encourage folks to try it out.

Comment: "In other words, the directory you start your R session from." — Which is generally *not* the directory where the code resides. For interactive RStudio projects and exploratory notebooks it happens to be the case but for other types of project it isn’t; notably, for any kind of self-contained application (e.g. command line utilities). Those are almost always launched in a directory that is completely unrelated to the location of the code. `here::here` does not work in those cases.

Answer (score 4):

`source` fundamentally doesn’t support this. The other answers show some workarounds that work in limited cases but all fail in some (common) cases. In particular, `chdir = TRUE` isn’t a good option as you noted yourself.

A better solution is to `box::use` from the ‘[**box**](https://github.com/klmr/box)’ package. This package allows you to treat R source code as proper *modules*. One property of this is that modules can load local modules.

Inside your `wrapper.R`, replace the `source` call by

```
box::use(./functions[...])
```

Or, if you want to *export* these functions from your `wrapper.R` module (rather than just using them internally), do the following instead:

```
#' @export
box::use(./functions[...])
```

And to load `wrapper.R` itself, use

```
box::use(project/wrapper)
```

Where `project` is the project name, and needs to correspond to the name of the folder that your `wrapper.R` script is saved in.

Please consult the [*Get started*](https://klmr.me/box/articles/box.html) vignette for more information on the usage of ‘box’ modules.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can define a helper function in `wrapper.R` that will try to load other files from the same directory. For example

```
source_here <- function(x, ...) {
    dir <- "."
    if(sys.nframe()>0) {
        frame <- sys.frame(1)
        if (!is.null(frame$ofile)) {
            dir <- dirname(frame$ofile)
        }
    }
    source(file.path(dir, x), ...)
}
```

Then you would call

```
# inside wrapper.R
source_here("functions.R")
```

Then you would just have source `wrapper.R` and it will look for `functions.R` in the same directory.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your code a little better. What is the point of having the `if(sys.nframe()>0)`?

Comment: Its probably overkill. I was at first running the code outside a function so there wasn't always a parent frame.

Comment: If `source_here` is in a different file, `wrapper.R` then how do your `source` it?

Comment: @PeterVermont `source_here` will only work for the file it's contained it. It cannot be included in a separate `wrapper.R` file or it will only look in the folder where **that** file is located.

Answer (score 2):

One answer I didn't see yet is to just use absolute paths. When you `source("myfunctions.R")` it's using the implicit relative path from `getwd()`. Use the full path to avoid problems when you change working directory.
Though, when sharing the work, the others will have to change all the paths by themselves.

Comment: Using absolute paths solves some problems, but creates others when the code is run in a slightly different tree. Other languages offer a little more, though I'm interested in looking at the "here" package mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but I ran into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35842119/3167040) on getting the directory where the script being sourced is.

I think you should be able to do this without installing additional packages:

```r
cur_dir = utils::getSrcDirectory(function(){})[1]
source(file.path(cur_dir, 'functions.R'))
```