# Can knitr source a script which sources a script from another folder?

Tags: r, knitr

I have a project where I put .rmd files in a separate folder called *docs*.  My R Markdown documents looks like this:

````
---
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
---
## R Markdown
```{r summary}
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = normalizePath("../"))
source('../test.R')
```
````

My *test.R* script, sitting in the root folder, looks like this:

```
source('helloWorld.R')
print("Hello World")
```

And the *helloWorld.R* script looks like this:

```
print("Hello World from separate script")
```

My two questions are:

1. Having set the root directory to "..", why do I still need to refer to the *test.R* using "../"?
2. Why does the source-within-a-source fail?  The above script works fine if I omit the *source* part of *test.R*?

Comment: Source is always relative to the current working directory, not the file itself. If you want to source from the same file, maybe try the solution at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815889/r-source-and-path-to-source-files/42816729#42816729

Comment: @MrFlick I appreciate the workaround:  I might use it if I can't figure out how to set the working directory from within my R Markdown script.

Comment: `setwd` will work within rmarkdown, although knitr might warn you about using it and will change back at the end of the chunk. In answer to your first question, knitr's `root_dir` is a knitr-specific option - it probably does not directly change the working directory.

Comment: @dash2 You're right!  Thank you.  If I replace my two lines of R code in my .rmd file with `setwd('..')` and `source('test.R')`, my script actually works just fine.

Comment: @dash2 Can you put your comment into an answer so I can vote it as the correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setwd` will work within rmarkdown, although knitr might warn you about using it and will change back at the end of the chunk. In answer to your first question, knitr's `root_dir` is a knitr-specific option - it probably does not directly change the working directory.