# How to run multiple rscript in a sequence?

Tags: r

I'm wondering if there is a way to run rscript within another script? like we do in Java

For example:- I have script-A, and script-b, so when I run script-b it should run script-a first automatically.

Comment: Call `source("script-a.R")` from near the top of script-b.  But see the cautions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815889/r-source-and-path-to-source-files

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `source()` function to run code in another file. So at the top of your script-b, just put `source('path/to/script-A.R')`.